# Article output at multilingual websites

Tags: joomla-2.5, multilingual

I have a Joomla 2.5 multilingual website (ua,ru,en).

I want to change a function, which is responsible for article output. This function should trim content (db column `introtext` table `_content`) by tags `<ua>/<ru>/<en>` and output only that part of article, which is enclosed in tags `<en></en>` for english, `<ua></ua>` for ukrainian, `<ru></ru>` for russian. So:

Result articles should look like:

```
<ua>bla blah</ua><ru>ololo lorem ipsum</ru><en>hello world!</en>
```

Then function should check `$_SERVER['REQUEST_URI']` and put language in `$lang` variable.

After that function should delete all code from `introtext` column except that is enclosed in `<$lang></$lang>` tags.

Can you help me to find where function of article output is?

Comment: It looks like you are not using the build-in multilanguage feature in Joomla.

Answer (score 3):

You might want to take a look at an extension called "[Easy Language](http://extensions.joomla.org/extensions/languages/multi-lingual-content/19439)". I haven't tried it myself, but according to the description it does exactly what you want (except the tags are a little different). In your case, your article would look like this:

```
{lang ua}bla blah{/lang}
{lang ru}ololo lorem ipsum{/lang}
{lang en}hello world!{/lang}
```

If you want to override the article output, you can create an override:

Copy the file `JOOMLAROOT\components\com_content\views\article\tmpl\default.php` to `\templates\YOURTEMPLATE\html\com_content\article\default.php` and edit the file as needed.

Answer (score 2):

Thanks, johanpw!
Next code solved my task:

`$lang = substr($_SERVER['REQUEST_URI'],1,2); 
echo substr($this->item->text, strpos($this->item->text,'{'.$lang.'}')+4, strpos($this->item->text,'{/'.$lang.'}') - strpos($this->item->text,'{'.$lang.'}')-4);`

...instead of:
`echo $this->item->text;`

P.S. I promise that I'll try to make some plugins in future.

Answer (score 0):

It seems that you will need to [develop a content plugin](http://docs.joomla.org/J2.5:Creating_a_content_plugin) for this and use [onContentPrepare](http://docs.joomla.org/Plugin/Events/Content) event to modify the output for your needs.

Comment: I don't know how to develop plugins and never did this before. I just want you to help me find code, which is responsible for article output.
Plugin development will help others, but I think I can't do this now.

Comment: Writing plugins is easier that you think. Anyway @johanpw pointed you to the plugin and code ;)